# Changing SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to use port 3307

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy to connect to my flask database, but because I am running two mysql dockers on an AWS machine, the referenced database is using port 3307 (not 3306).  How would I amend these statements to reference the correct port.

environment variable:

````
export RDR_LOGIN="mysql+pymysql://user:useraddr@<ip_addr>/<dbase_name>"```
````

config.py

```
class Config:
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('RDR_LOGIN')
```

**init**.py

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

Comment: export RDR_LOGIN="mysql+pymysql://user:useraddr@<ip_addr:port>/<dbase_name>"```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

snakecharmerb's comment did the trick.

```
export RDR_LOGIN="mysql+pymysql://user:useraddr@<ip_addr:3307>/<dbase_name>"
```